# Questions regarding Royal Gorge Railroad War in Colorado

Tags: war, old-west, railroads

I am seeking information about the Colorado Railroad War, also known as the Royal Gorge Railroad War, in the Royal Gorge, Colorado. I am specifically wondering if this conflict was resolved through a few "show down" gun fights or if it involved partisan conflict and sabotage between workers from both railroad companies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because resource requests are off-topic per the [help/on-topic]

Comment: One thing you might consider is removing the request for resources and simply leave the conflict resolution part. Any answers would be expected to cite resources, so you might end up getting what you want anyway.

Comment: You might get a bit more attention to the question if you mention that the conflict included both Bat Masterson and Doc Holiday as hired guns for one side.